# XSLT 1.0 Using for-each loop to populate table with a call-template

Tags: foreach, widget, xslt-1.0

So I recently started working with XSL 1.0 on a project and needed to iterate over a node-set and for each node make a call out to a template with "attributes" from the node.
I say "attributes" because I ended up just making an inner tag, ie. the node-set I'm iterating over looks like this:

```
<var>  
  <key>key 1 text here</key>  
  <value>value 1 text here</value>  
</var>  
  ....  
<var>  
  <key>key Nth text here</key>  
  <value>value Nth text here</value>  
</var>
```

Though I could go back to something like `<var key="keytext" value="valtext" />` and use actual attributes if someone thinks that's better (in fact it's the way I first approached this issue but had no luck with it).
Anyway, this node-set is being used to populate a form. The user selects a Project Name from a dropdown menu, which populates the Plan Name dropdown menu. Once the user then selects a plan name, there is a table on the form called Build Variables that gets populated with the key/value pairings for that plan. If the user changes the plan name, then the build variables change (I've already taken care of page refresh and reload and making sure the old variables are wiped) and the number of rows in the table is likely to change (one row of the table per key/value pair).

This is the relevant portion of the XSL that gets the node-set of `<var>` tags and assigns it to `$variables` then uses a `<for-each>` to iterate over them, grab the key/value pairs and pass them to the template "widget_render" (I'm not putting up the widget_render code since it's extremely verbose (greater than 150 lines) and makes calls to other templates based on what params it gets passed). In this particular case, all widget_render, is essentially create a text area box and populate it with the content of the key or value - the box for the key cannot be edited by the user, but the box it creates for the value can be. Here's the code:

```
<xsl:variable name="variables" select="bamb-class:getPlanVariables($projVal, $planVal)" />    
<xsl:for-each select="$variables">  
   <xsl:variable name="key" select="./key" />  
   <xsl:variable name="value" select="./value"/>  
   <tr height="30">  
      <td class="datacell" colspan="1">  
         <xsl:call-template name="widget_render">  
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldName" select="concat('keyField[', position(), ']')"/>  
            <xsl:with-param name="renderCmd" select="'input'" />  
            <xsl:with-param name="default" select="$key" />  
            <xsl:with-param name="readOnly" select="'true'" />  
         </xsl:call-template>  
      </td>  
      <td class="datacell" colspan="1">  
         <xsl:call-template name="widget_render">  
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldName" select="concat('valueField[', position(), ']')"/>  
            <xsl:with-param name="renderCmd" select="'input'"/>  
            <xsl:with-param name="default" select="$value" />  
         </xsl:call-template>  
      </td>  
   </tr>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hopefully that's enough background on what I'm doing so that this makes sense. Let me know if it doesn't.

My issue is this: the key and value seem to get lost inside the call-template to widget_render. Meaning that no input box with text appears in either `<td>` tag in the table.

However I can do `<xsl:value-of select="$key" />` and `<xsl:value-of select="$value" />` inside the appropiate `<td>` tag and it outputs the correct value (the information is there, just not being passed into widget_render or something).
With no `value-of` statements all I'm currently getting are the correct number of rows, but they're all blank.

And yes, I have to use the widget_render template (can't just put in an `<input>` tag or something) since the software later re-uses the widget_render logic on the table to perform other operations. And no, it's not a type clash or something where I pass in a wrong type, I made sure of that.

I don't know if it's something really asinine that I am missing or if there's something larger that I just don't understand, but this one has me stumped.

So to put it succinctly: Why is the call-template (seemingly) not working and populating the table with the key/value pairs in the for-each loop? Even when I know the for-each is iterating over the correct node-set and `$key` and `$value` have the correct assignments at each iteration.

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thanks! Let me know if anything is unclear or if there's any information I unwittingly left out that needs to be known. If needed I could throw up the widget_render code as well, but I doubt that would actually be helpful to anyone.

EDIT:
Here's a link to a dropbox with the whole file: widget_render starts on line 119
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zt3g9idprrca6ak/default-widgets.xml
It's a very long template, and all the other templates it calls are in that file as well.

Comment: Could you please append the widget_render template?

Comment: Sure thing - just edited and added a link to it.

Comment: I guess the context is changing in the `<xsl:for-each select="$variables">`. So I think `<xsl:for-each select="//fieldDef[@name=$fieldName]">` in called template cannot "see" the document. Try (with some static values, just for checking) call template outside the first for-each. If it worked it would be it.

Comment: Ah you're right - any ideas on how to break out of the scope of the `for-each` so that it can "see" the document then? Haven't found any really useful XPath expressions or XSL tricks to do that.

Comment: It depends - sometimes you could "store" the input xml into a variable and used it in for-each (e.g. pass it into called template as other parameter) for other processing.

Comment: Hmmm, guess I'll try messing around with that for a bit, see if it gets me anywhere. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure out a solution - seems kind of like a hack to me, but it works and works well for what I need.

I replaced the loop with this:

```
<xsl:variable name="planVariables" select="bamb-class:getPlanVariables($projVal, $planVal)"/>
<xsl:call-template name="renderAllRows">
    <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="count($planVariables)"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="planVariables" select="$planVariables"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Which then makes a call out to renderAllRows which recursively calls itself to simulate the `xsl:for-each` loop until all the rows in the table have been rendered.

```
<xsl:template name="renderAllRows">
    <xsl:param name="i" />
    <xsl:param name="count" />
    <xsl:param name="planVariables" />
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
    <xsl:call-template name="renderRow" >
            <xsl:with-param name="rowNum" select="$i"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="planVariables" select="$planVariables"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
<!-- recursion here -->
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
        <xsl:call-template name="renderAllRows">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="planVariables" select="$planVariables"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="renderRow">
    <xsl:param name="rowNum"/>
    <xsl:param name="planVariables"/>
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="exsl:node-set($planVariables)[position()=$rowNum]/key"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="exsl:node-set($planVariables)[position()=$rowNum]/value"/>
    <tr height="30">
        <td class="datacell" colspan="1">
            <xsl:call-template name="widget_render">
                <xsl:with-param name="fieldName" select="concat('keyField[', $rowNum, ']')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="renderCmd" select="'input'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="default" select="$key" />
                <xsl:with-param name="readOnly" select="'true'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
        <td class="datacell" colspan="1">
            <xsl:call-template name="widget_render">
                <xsl:with-param name="fieldName" select="concat('valueField[', $rowNum, ']')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="renderCmd" select="'input'"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="default" select="$value" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
    </tr>                
</xsl:template>
```

And that got everything working properly, the calls out to widget_render are looking at the right context, creating the textboxes they should and populating them. Thanks to Jirka for the tips that helped me fix this.